# Programmatically Labeling a Signal in Simulink

Tags: matlab, properties, signals, line, simulink

I'm attempting to write a script that generates a basic Simulink model and I'd like to know if there's a way to programmatically label a signal line.  I've looked at the add_line function (which is what I'm using to add the lines), but I don't see an option for defining anything like a Name or Label property.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the currently selected block `gcb` or the name of the block whose output signal you want to name, you can write

> ```
> name = gcb
> h = get_param(name, 'PortHandles')
>
> h = 
>   Inport: [72.0029 73.0029]
>  Outport: 74.0029
>   Enable: []
>  Trigger: []
>    State: []
>    LConn: []
>    RConn: []
> Ifaction: []
>
> set(h.Outport(1), 'SignalNameFromLabel', 'output_sig')
> ```

Answer (score 6):

`add_line` returns a handle to the newly created line, so you could also write:

```
lineHandle = add_line('sys','oport','iport');
set_param(lineHandle, 'Name', 'yourSignalName');
```