# How can I name signals in Simulink's scope?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am plotting a lot of signals in one Scope block. Is it possible to name the different signals/figures for a better overview?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I looked through the menus about 5 times looking for how to do this before giving up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Scope window, select `View>Legend` option to view different signals and you can easily change the name of the signals in legend window.

Comment: or by naming the connections to the scope

Answer (score 3):

If you double click on a signal, a small text entry field will appear that allows you to name it.

[image: An image of a signal with a name going into a scope.]

The name of the signal will then appear in the scope's ledgend.
[image: An image of the scope showing the signal's name.]

Comment: Is it possible to automate the same using Matlab code?

Comment: @SivaramBoina, I don't know off the top of my head. I would suggest asking a new question so that you can get a response from somebody more knowledgable.

Comment: There's a method for setting signal names programmatically  given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18981959/6651650